# TimeSpan FormatString with optional hours

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a timespan, `ts`, that has mostly minutes and seconds, but sometimes hours.
I'd like `ts` to return a formatted string that'll give the following results:

```
3:30 (hours not displayed, showing only full minutes)
13:30 
1:13:30 (shows only full hours instead of 01:13:30)
```

So far I have:

```
string TimeSpanText = string.Format("{0:h\\:mm\\:ss}", MyTimeSpan);
```

but it's not giving the above results. How can I achieve the results I want?

Comment: What you want and what you get is not clear?

Comment: I'm looking for the formatstring that'll return a string with the above format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think a single format string will give you what you want, but building the output yourself is a simple task:

```
public string FormatTimeSpan(TimeSpan ts)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    if ((int) ts.TotalHours > 0)
    {
        sb.Append((int) ts.TotalHours);
        sb.Append(":");
    }

    sb.Append(ts.Minutes.ToString("m"));
    sb.Append(":");
    sb.Append(ts.Seconds.ToString("ss"));

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**EDIT: Better idea!**

You could make the method above an extension method on the `TimeSpan` class like so:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToMyFormat(this TimeSpan ts)
    {
        // Code as above.
    }
}
```

Then using this is as simple as invoking `ts.ToMyFormat()`.

Comment: I love the idea of creating an extension method!!

Comment: There is one little logic bug; if seconds are between 0 and 9, the output of 5 minutes and 3 seconds looks like 5:3 instead of 5:03. I'm working on it. Thanks for showing me how extension methods work; you read about them but when you build your own for the first time, you see how they really work for you. Thanks.

Comment: Here's for the seconds:if (ts.Seconds < 10)
{ sb.Append(":0"); }
else { sb.Append(":"); }

Comment: Because `ts.Minutes` is an int, the code should be modified to read `ts.Minutes.ToString("d2")`

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you want something like

```
string TimeSpanText = string.Format(
    MyTimeSpan.TotalHours >= 1 ? @"{0:h\:mm\:ss}" : @"{0:mm\:ss}",
    MyTimeSpan);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! `Hr:Min(2):Sec(2)` or `Min:Sec(2)`.